# JQuery - Filtering elements by attribute in jquery each

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to push data-type value of all visible rows into an array how do I do it using jquery?

I did something like this but I'm pretty sure its incorrect as its not working.

```
var myArray = [];

            $('#myTableId tbody tr').each(function() {
                myArray.push($(this).not('.class="hidden"').data('type'));
            });
```

Comment: well we sure can't help without seeing first what your html looks like and second knowing what your expected results are. Please review what a [mcve] is

Comment: `.class="hidden"` is an invalid selector. Do you mean `$(this).not('.hidden')`?

Comment: its just a table with many rows, some hidden. they also have a data-type attribute which i'm trying to push into an array only if they are on a visible row.

Comment: Terry, you're right! damn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use map() and  use `not()` before looping

```
var myArray =  $('#myTableId tbody tr').not('.hidden').map(function(){
   return $(this).data('type')
}).get();
```

You could do same with `$.each` also...the `not()` would remain the same

Comment: And `data` is probably not the right choice here, unless the OP is really using the features `data` provides. Per the question, they just want the attriubute value, which would be `attr("data-type")`. (Remember: `data` is not an accessor for `data-*` attributes. It's both more and less than that.)

Comment: You can use `:not(.hidden)` as well, to offload that to the browser's selector engine: `$('#myTableId tbody tr:not(.hidden)')...` [`:not`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) was added five years ago, so should command solid support these days.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but jQuery `data()` **is** an accessor for `data-` attributes

Comment: No, it isn't. It's an accessor for jQuery's data cache. The data cache initializes from `data-*` attributes, but is then entirely separate from it. `data` never writes to `data-*` attributes, which can be significant, and moreover duplicates the data in the cache unnecessarily if you only actually need the attribute value. It also *processes* the data, which the OP may or may not want. Given `<div data-foo="5"></div>`, for instance, `typeof $(theDiv).data("foo")` is `number`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok...my bad as far as accessing *attributes*... i get what you are saying. really can't see how processing it would be unwanted...other than performance time

Answer (score 1):

[As per my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540006/jquery-filtering-elements-by-attribute-in-jquery-each/39540046#comment66394074_39540006), the selector you are using is incorrect. Using `.hidden` in the `.not()` method should be sufficient, i.e.:

```
var myArray = [];

 $('#myTableId tbody tr').each(function() {
      var t = $(this).not('.hidden').data('type');
      if(!!t)
          myArray.push(t);
});
```

Here's a proof-of-concept example:

```js
$(function(){
var myArray = [];
    
    $('#myTableId tbody tr').each(function() {
      var t = $(this).not('.hidden').data('type');
      if(!!t)
        myArray.push(t);
    });

  console.log(myArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-type="lorem"><td>lorem (not .hidden)</td></tr>
     <tr class="hidden" data-type="ipsum"><td>ipsum (.hidden)</td></tr>
     <tr data-type="dolor"><td>dolor (not .hidden)</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

And this is assuming that your markup is also correct.

Comment: doesn't make sense even with proper selector

Comment: @KevinB How is `$(this).not('.hidden').data('type')` not a value?

Comment: @Terry will end up pushing a bunch of `undefined`'s on rows that are hidden

Comment: @charlietfl Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function as below:

```
var myArray = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myTableId tr').each( function() {
     if (! $(this).hasClass('hidden'))
        myArray.push($(this).data('type'));
   });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rzj91us9/)